# VS 2022 Xamarin CS7027 Error signing output with public key from file -- Invalid Public Key

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I can't get past this error CS7027.  I have seen several other posts about CS7027 regarding missing file.  This is NOT a missing file.  The file is there in the directory.  The error says "Invalid Public Key".  Any help would be appreciated.  Is this an error to be resolved in the apple developer account on on the mac mini itself or in visual studio in the project / solution?

I have tried everything I can think of from re-creating and downloading certificates (both app development and ios Development), setting them to Always Trust to make them trusted, manual and automatic bundle signing and selecting both certificates in assembly signing.

I can run the app in the iOS mobile emulator. It just will not deploy to my Ipad.

Comment: Did you create the config file and download it in VS? the profile all the public keys associated with your certificates, while the copy on your local Mac contains all the private keys. For the certificates to be valid, the key pairs must match. You can refer to the document: [Manual provisioning for Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=windows)

Comment: I followed all the steps here in this link you sent.  The error is still there.  It even says "Error signing output with public key from file ..../.../Downloads/development-2.cer' -- Invalid public key.  So it sees the file but just apparently cant use it I guess.  I went into the key manager and made sure the certificate is fully Trusted also.

Comment: Did you try cleaning the wrong folder( ..../.../Downloads/development-2.cer') and try again.

Comment: You can go to [apple developer](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2Faccount%2F&rv=1) and check if the cer has been revoke.